# Declare statement in PL/SQL for a part of the query

Tags: oracle, plsql, union, declare

I have a query like the following:

```
select t1.varid, t1.var1, t1.var2, t1.vardata, t2.varid, t2.var1, t2,.var2 
from   table1 t1, table2 t2
where  t1.varid = t2.varid
and    t1.vardata between to_date('20170807','YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20170808','YYYYMMDD')
```

Now the question is:
I need to extract the data not only in the data range specified in the query above, but I want to extract many other ranges in the same query.

To do that, I used `UNION ALL` and it works. The problem is that I have to re-write this part many times:

```
select t1.varid, t1.var1, t1.var2, t1.vardata, t2.varid, t2.var1, t2, var2 
from   table1 t1, table2 t2
where  t1.varid = t2.varid
```

Is there a tip for how to define `select t1.varid...` as a named variable in order to avoid a long boring repeated query?

Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: Not in atleast `SQL`. Alternatively you can write a procedure and pass date range to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi XING, i don't understand: is it not possible to: define (select var1, var2,... from table) as namevariable ? It seems very strange...

Comment: I meant to say, you cannot avoid long boring `UNION ALL`.  Also whatd the problem when you put a OR cluase with differnt time range in your query.

Comment: ok good, but how to semplify this part: (select var1, var2,... from table) in other to every union all not to rewrite it...

Comment: Check my answer. This is what i was asking. Is there any problem if you do it like i showed you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the chat you can do it as below:

```
SELECT t1.varid  as col1,
       t1.var1   as col2,
       t1.var2,
       t1.vardata,
       t2.varid,
       t2.var1,
       t2,
       .var2
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE     t1.varid = t2.varid
       AND t1.vardata BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20170807', 'YYYYMMDD')
                          AND TO_DATE ('20170808', 'YYYYMMDD')
        --- Give date ranges.                  
       OR   t1.vardata BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20170907', 'YYYYMMDD')
                          AND TO_DATE ('20171008', 'YYYYMMDD')                  
       OR ....
       OR ....
```

Comment: Really thanks XING, so is not necessary to use Union all, but the solutin was to use OR for the ranges..

Comment: I thake this oppurtunity to ask you also how to defina as variabe the part "select... from.." is it possible to define this part as "namevariable"?

Comment: Thats true. If your tables is `same` and the only changing part is date range then `OR` should do the job. You can `Alias` a column name. See in example

Comment: `"select... from.." is it possible to define this part as "namevariable`. Its possible but in `PLSQ` not in plain `SQL`

Comment: Sure, just let me create a new queston.

Comment: mmh, iI can post a question every 90 min.. so I will post it later and I will let you now the title of the queston. thanks

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You can google how to create dynamic query in PLSQL. There are many links avaiale on that

Comment: Very good, I will check it. But within 90 min I will try to re-create the question...

Comment: Please don't create a new question until you have searched this site for questions on `[oracle]+[dynamic-sql]`. There's a lot of information for Seekers here, and it is likely you can solve your issue **now** by reading some existing answers.

Comment: Hi XING, I created the queston: Define Select statement as variable in ORALCE PLSQL, if yuoi want, check it. Thank you.

Comment: So, did you undertake the research I suggested before you asked your new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching the dates directly from a table like this instead of rewriting repeated statements :

```
Select 'select t1.varid, t1.var1, t1.var2, t1.vardata, t2.varid, t2.var1, t2,.var2 
From table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.varid = t2.varid and t1.vardata between to_date('''+MY_DATE+''', ''yyyymmdd'')'  from tableofdate
```

Below is the schema i used.This is just a sample.Please edit it as per your requirements

```
create table tableofdate(my_date varchar(100))
insert into tableofdate values ('20170808')
```

Comment: Thak you, bu i prefer to not create a table.